# Spring @Configurable on abstract class: the hierarchy of the type is inconsistent

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I am using Eclipse Juno with AspectJ and compile time weaving, and I see this annoying error message when I have this scenario:

```
@Configurable(preConstruction = true)
public abstract class AbstractEntity {  

    @Resource private Service service;

    public AbstractEntity () {
         service.doSomething();
    }
}

public class Response extends AbstractEntity {  

    public Response() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The marker doesn't show up in the problems tab, it just shows a red x marker on the class declaration for Response. Cleaning doesn't change anything, however, if I move the @Configurable annotation to the Response class and remove it from the AbstractEntity, the error marker goes away but I get a NPE when the super constructor tries to touch the injected service.

Its also important to mention that this error marker doesnt actually break anything, if I leave the code the way it is everything works fine, I just always see that error marker whenever I open the class (and on any class that extends AbstractEntity).

Is there any way to stop this message from showing? is CTW changing the constructor hierarchy behind the scenes which causes this message?